# Unable to copy & paste in Jmeter running on Mac Mac OS X - High Sierra 10.13.3

Tags: macos, jmeter

Facing the incredibly annoying problem with Jmeter that I can't copy and paste.

This is strictly when running in GUI mode. This is version 3.3

Are there any settings which should be changed or should I try reinstalling ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try upgrading to Apache [JMeter 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4) (or whatever latest version is available from [JMeter Downloads Page](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi)) it might be the case it is already fixed. Moreover, according to [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) users are encouraged to go for the latest available version
2. Try using "alternative" keyboard shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, it might be the case that JMeter developers intentionally or by accident don't use underlying OS shortcuts or look-and-feel
3. If it is really annoying you can try raising an issue in [JMeter Bugzilla](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html), however in this case you will definitely have to upgrade to JMeter 4.1